# Maven picking up old dependencies

Tags: maven, kotlin

I have a multi-module project with a complicated set of dependencies arising from inheriting from a large parent POM (like an "include everything" POM that is used by all of our company's projects) and including a number of our company's dependencies which themselves include many transitive dependencies.

My problem is I want to use the latest Kotlin 1.6.10. I have this in my main pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But I notice that my Kotlin classes and functions are still taken from the older Kotlin 1.5.31. When I do `mvn dependency:tree` I see the following:

```
[INFO] \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.6.10:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.5.31:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.5.31:compile
[INFO]    \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.5.31:compile
```

This is the only section that mentions the Kotlin standard library. There are no direct inclusions of `kotlin-stdlib.jar`, only as a transitive dependency of `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar`. So why does `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.jar` 1.6.10 include `kotlin-stdlib.jar` 1.5.31? This doesn't happen with my personal projects - there, it's all 1.6.10 for everything. What Maven goals or other techniques are available to investigate what is causing 1.5.31 to be pulled in?

Comment: the effective pom may help you find where which dependency/information is exactly coming from... ( `mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose=true` ( you may want to add `-Doutput=effective-pom.xml` to save the output to file )

Comment: @Roland thanks, with your hint I managed to find the hidden culprit. It showed that those dependencies came from `kotlin-bom` version 1.5.31, which wasn't much help, but I then `grep`'d through my `.m2/repository` and found the chain of dependencies leading to that.